# Extracting anchor links along with associated text from a site using webcrawler outputs nothing

Tags: php, web-crawler

I  been trying to extract some links along with their associated text from a site/page using web crawler. but seems like i missed something, which results to a blank page. Hoping you guys can point that mistake of mine/

HTML page as goes::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="NeededDiv">
        <a href="link">text</a>
        <a href="link">text</a>
        <a href="link">text</a>
        <a href="link">text</a>
        <a href="link">text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ExtraDiv">
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

the php code as goes::

```
<?php
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$returned_content = get_data('file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/h/1.html');

$first_step = explode( '<div class="NeededDiv">' , $returned_content );
$second_step = explode('</div>', $first_step[0]);
$third_step = explode('</a>', $second_step[0]);
?>
```

so, here i m trying to extract a specific div from the page using the php page. i opened the php page through xampp local host..

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: There's no need to roll your own HTML parser. You should look into [PHP's DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead. It's a better way to parse HTML using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
<?php
$returned_content='<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="NeededDiv">
        <a href="link">text</a>
        <a href="link">text</a>
        <a href="link">text</a>
        <a href="link">text</a>
        <a href="link">text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ExtraDiv">
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
    </div>
</body>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($returned_content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute( 'href' )."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: no man, they are different pages,. the html content is from another site , while the php content is on my page,. so, when i open my page (php content) it should extract said div class links and text to the screen..

Comment: Pretty sure it's what you need. Just set `$returned_content` to the return of your `get_data()` function